# Join data from one column in to another column as a separate row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
    Year1   Year2   Total
0   2010    2011    2500
1   2012    2013    3000
2   2014    2015    4000
```

I want to grab the data in the `Year2` column and merge it with the `Year1` column, and keep the `Total` value associated with it, which should look like:

```
    Year1   Total
0   2010    2500
1   2011    2500
2   2012    3000
3   2013    3000
4   2014    4000
5   2015    4000
```

I have considered first of all duplicating the `df` so that I get the second 'Total' value for the 2011, 2013 and 2015

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 2, axis=0))
df.columns = ['Year1', 'Year2', 'Total']
```

but I'm still unsure of the steps to merge the column data from `Year2` to `Year1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `melt` it:

```
out = (pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Total']).rename(columns={'value':'Year1'})
       .drop(columns='variable')[['Year1', 'Total']]
       .sort_values(by='Year1').reset_index(drop=True))
```

or `set_index` with "Total" + `unstack`:

```
out = (df.set_index('Total').unstack().droplevel(0)
       .reset_index(name='Year1')[['Year1', 'Total']]
       .sort_values(by='Year1').reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
   Year1  Total
0   2010   2500
1   2011   2500
2   2012   3000
3   2013   3000
4   2014   4000
5   2015   4000
```

Comment: This works - what if I had an additional column in the dataframe but ultimately it should remain untouched, eg a column called 'Name' that contained text as a string.

Comment: @seevans38 should it be repeated like Total column here?

Comment: Yes it should repeat twice for both years

Comment: @seevans38 then include it in id_vars in melt like Total

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output using `append` function but with a few steps before:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('df.txt')
newDf = df[["Year2", "Total"]].rename(columns={"Year2":"Year1"})
df.drop(columns=["Year2"], inplace=True)
resultDf = df.append(newDf)
resultDf.sort_values("Year1")
```

##### Output

| Year1 | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2500 |
| 2011 | 2500 |
| 2012 | 3000 |
| 2013 | 3000 |
| 2014 | 4000 |
| 2015 | 4000 |